# Send logs to new relic through my javascript application

Tags: javascript, logging, browser, newrelic, apm

I know that on java applications you can use new relic to send your logs using an agent and everything you log on stdout will be sent to new relic.

For javascript applications running on client side, is that possible to do the same?
What I would like to do is something like:

newRelic.info('I was here);
newRelic.error('throw an error' error)

Answer (score 0):

New Relic does have a solution for monitoring JavaScript applications.  They call it [Browser](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/browser/new-relic-browser/getting-started/introduction-browser-monitoring) monitoring.  There are several ways to get setup for your application to start using it and the link should provide you everything you need to get going.  I haven't used it yet. I came upon your post doing a search for the exact same thing.